# Static UITableViewCell returns nil on CellForRowAtIndexPath, but only for certain sections

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have defined a table view controller using static cells in a Storyboard scene.
The table view itself contains six sections, each of which contains one or two cells.
I write data to the cells from this method in my view controller:

```
- (void)setUpAllCells
{
    //Charge Name
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    TableViewCellTextField *currentTextField = (TableViewCellTextField *)[[self tableView] cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
    [currentTextField.textField setDelegate:self];

    //Charge Description
    path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
    currentTextField = (TableViewCellTextField *)[[self tableView] cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
    [currentTextField.textField setDelegate:self];

    ...

    path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:5];
    TableViewCellControl *currentControl = (TableViewCellControl *)[[self tableView] cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
    [currentControl setValue:m_data->trailBurnTime];
}
```

Which is called from:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self setUpAllCells];
}
```

When I run the application, each cell responds as I expect except for the last section.
The last section's cells are not connected to my controller and retain their default values from the storyboard scene.  I set a breakpoint in setUpAllCells and found that cellForRowAtIndexPath is returning nil for that last section.

I've used this format for five other view controllers, and have not had this happen.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- I tested this with my own custom TableViewCells and, when those didn't work, standard UITableViewCells.  The last section always returns nil.
- I rearranged the sections and cells. The last section always returns nil.
- I removed that section completely. The other sections still work normally without it.
- I added more sections. Anything from section 5 on returns nil at CellForRowAtIndexPath.

I'm at a loss here.  I can't figure out what could be causing this.

Suggestions?

Comment: If your table view has 6 sections, then there is no section 6 as you have in your last bit of code.

Comment: @rdelmar Whoops.  I typed that in wrong.  It was a 5 in my original code.  That was left over from the testing I did as described at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you get the results you do -- when I tried it, and logged the cells, I only got valid cells for the first 3 sections. Anything past section 2 was null. Frankly, I'm not sure why it works at all, since this isn't the way Apple says to populate a static table view. You're supposed to create IBOutlets in your table view controller to the UI elements in your cells. In this regard, a static table view acts more like a scroll view with subviews, than it does like a table view. You can also make IBOutlets to the cells themselves instead of the individual UI elements, and then use dot notation to address any of the properties in your custom cell, or the standard ones like textLabel and detailTextLabel.

Comment: Yeah, that was it.  I removed the calls to CellForRowAtIndexPath and created IBOutlets for my cells.  Now, everything works fine.  I believe the reason it was working for most of the cells is that they were on the screen.  That is, only the cells that were below the screen when the view loaded didn't work.  I think it's because the table view only loads visible cells initially.  So, when I tried to access the cells with CellForRowAtIndexPath, there was no data beyond the sixth section.

Answer (score 0):

The funny story about your question is that when you call the function cellForRowAtIndexPath on your tableview, I believe it in turn calls the delegate callback function you are supposed to implement as a UITableViewDelegate that provides the TableView with the cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Once you implement that function you will get the cell back.  I think the function you are looking for is:

```
– dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:
– dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
```

Look here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

I know thats not likely the answer you were looking for but its the truth :).

Comment: Those are table view methods.  I'm creating a custom table view controller, not a table view.  Since I'm not overriding the base implementation, I don't think I need to do that.